# How can I assign one contact to one of the team workers?

Tags: contacts, joomla

Right now everybody have access to the info of all the contacts. And we need that only specific people of our team get access to the info of a specific group of people.

How do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

ACL or Access Controls should be able to do that. 
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/

BUT... I've never worked with Joomla so can't offer any further advice

Answer (score 1):

You can create ACL through UI if you have very limited group if you have 50+ groups and will increase going forward than would recommend to write a small extension that implements ACL civi hook to control the action on contact.

Some useful docs to configure ACL via UI:

http://www.gingerfeet.net/civicrm_access_control_lists

http://www.gingerfeet.net/civicrm_access_control_lists

For some use case you may like to use below extension

https://civicrm.org/extensions/autogroup-helper-for-group-based-acl-environments